# workflow of $_SERVER in php

Tags: php, html

I was reading code something like this:

```
<body>
  <?php
    function getFileUploadForm(){
      return '<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="file1">Upload a file</label>
          <input type="file" name="file1" id="file1" />
          <p class="help-block" id="errordiv">Browse for a file and post it to the server.</p>
       </div>
       <input type="submit" />
     </form>';
    }
  ?>

  <header>
    <h1>Using $_FILES and $_POST</h1>
  </header>

  <div class='container'>
  <?php 
    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
      echo "File was sent to server <a href=''>Upload another file</a>";
    } else {
      echo getFileUploadForm();
    }
  ?>
  </div>
</body>
```

To my surprise, the script produces a form in first, but what's the value of `$_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]`? I haven't submit any form yet. And if I submit the a form using post, then it echo "File was sent to server", but the workflow is so weird, it starts from "else" then to "if" condition, how could it be?

[image]

Comment: I think your problem is your specific instance of PHP / Server / browser file handling.
I ran your code in FireFox, Chrome and IE10 and didn't once get a return of both results as you've described.
The issue is not with PHP `$_SERVER` but is somehow to do with how your implementation of the code / server / browser is working, or other parts of your code unshown in this question.
My PHP: 5.6.2

Answer (score 2):

By default `$_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]` is value is `GET` so when if condition checking `if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")` then else condition will execute. for example in your code

```
<?php
function getFileUploadForm(){
return '<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">

 <div class="form-group">
   <label for="file1">Upload a file</label>
   <input type="file" name="file1" id="file1" />
   <p class="help-block" id="errordiv">Browse for a file and post it to the server.</p>
</div>
<input type="submit" />
</form>';
}
?>

<header>
<h1>Using $_FILES and $_POST</h1>
<?php echo 'Before checking if else condition='.$_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]; ?>
</header>

<div class='container'>
<?php 

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
echo "File was sent to server <a href=''>Upload another file</a>".$_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"];
}
else {
echo getFileUploadForm();

}
?>
</div>
```

For more detail i have printed below code before if else that time you can see the value of the `$_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"];` is `GET`

```
 <?php echo 'Before checking if else condition='.$_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]; ?>
```

**Updated**

when you access this `php` file the execution will start from first line as it comes to if  condition then it will check `$_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == POST` or `GET` but by **default** `$_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] is GET` so it will execute else statement .When you submit form `$_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]` will take method from form so it will be equal to `Post` so if will exicute

Comment: but afyer I submit a form, the script should do nothing, but actually it went back to "if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")", because I was getting  the message "File was sent to server", so it started from else back to if, how could it be? so it is like do...while loop, but there isn't a loop, is it?

Comment: Thank u for ur answer. I undertsand the default method is get,but I still don't get the workflow. When the script first comes acrros the if statement, because of the default get method,getFileUploadForm() is called. But the script already passed the if staement as else is the last piece script, so the script should be supposed to be finished, how come it jump back to the if statement again?

Comment: when you click submit $_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]  will reset to form method .you have post in your form

Comment: I mean even the latest $_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD] is post now, since the workflow has already passed the if , it cannot be checked again by if condition

Comment: when you refresh page it will reset to default

Comment: I added a picture to the question to explain what my questions is. Yes, I fully understand when I click submit $_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"], the method changes to post, but even that, it should not be checked again in the if statement,because it was called by the function in "else" statement which is the end of the script.

Comment: @Dong clicking submit causes a new client side request for the server side script, effectively executing the entire script again using a `POST` request method. It is the same as clicking a link to a different page entirely.

Comment: @fyrye Thank you I see

Comment: @fyrye  is it a default setting that when submiting a form, it will execute the script again even there is no href attribute?

Comment: @Dong depends on the browser and your `DOCTYPE` specification or if it is overridden with ECMAScript. Normally it defaults to the current page. It is more visible if you set the request method attribute to `get` which will append `?` with the input fields to the query string of the browser URL. See your specified html `DOCTYPE` specification for the form action attribute to determine its functionality. http://w3c.github.io/html/sec-forms.html#element-attrdef-form-action (HTML5.2 spec)

Comment: @Dong it is considered a best practice to specify the `action` attribute, even if the desired action is to submit to the same script, like so `<form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars(PHP_SELF); ?>"`. This will prevent development of invalid HTML 4.0 and XHTML 1.0. https://validator.w3.org/ Otherwise in general, every PHP request is processed on the server before being sent fully to the client. So the client must always send a new request in order for it be processed. Though some more advanced techniques can be used to leave an open request (push/comet request).

Answer (score 0):

It says.

**If** form was posted, just tell the user that file was uploaded to the server. **Else** draw file-upload form.

Functions are not executed until they are called.

Answer (score -3):

try to use:

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] === "POST")
```

i mean `===` instead of `==`

Comment: This doesn't matter because you can't have a non-string with the value "POST", so checking the value *Type* is unnessecary.